# Custom Post Type: find by meta attribute

Tags: wordpress, loops, hook, custom-post-type

I tag my blog 'articles', which are custom post types, with a few attributes which can have a value from *0 - 100*.

My goal is it, to access those custom post type records by letting the user select the attribute values on a range slider and show the most fitting.

E.g.:
Two article have the following attributes:

- Article 1: **funny**: 30  **sarcastic:** 80  **drama:** 10
- Article 2: **funny**: 10  **sarcastic:** 90  **drama:** 5

**Search Cases:**

- If the user is searching for *funny: 10* he should get *Article 2* above *Article 1*
- If the user is searching for *funny: 20* he should get *Article 1* above *Article 2* because of ascending order.
- If the user is searching for *funny: 21* he should get *Article 1* above *Article 2*

The attributes should be combinable between each other.

I have no clue how to start.

My first approach was the following code, but I don't know if this is the right path to go.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'article',
   'meta_query' => array(
       'relation' => 'AND',
       array(
           'key' => 'attr_funny',
           'value' => array('50', '100'),
           'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
           'type' => 'NUMERIC',
       ),
   ),
);
```

Thank in advance for any input!

Answer (score 1):

I would use Advanced Custom Fields to add the attributes to that post type and then isotope to filter the posts by funny, sarcastic, ect.

ACF: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
Isotope: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I already use ACF for adding attributes. Isotope is only handling existing data, as far as I can see. But since the articles will be 5000+ I think it should be done by querying the correct data and not by sorting the existing data. What do you think about that?

Comment: Use the WP REST API plugin